# Comparing values from the user input datagridview and a table from microsoft access

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make a sudoku puzzle where a user types in all their values on the datagridview on the windows form and then when they click submit the user input values are compared with a table from access which already has the solutions saved and then which ever cells are incorrect they change to red. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I was thinking maybe having a second datagridview which is hidden but which contains the solutions and comparing them that way but i was wondering if there was a better option using SQL.

Comment: on the SQL side these might help you out https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solve-sudoku-with-t-sql-part-1-1

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/the-sudoku-puzzle-generator/